# Trouble declaring and recognizing global functions

Tags: c++, function

I've created some mathematical functions that will be used in main() and by member functions in multiple host classes. I was thinking it would be easiest to make these math functions global in scope, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I've currently put all the functions in a file called Rdraws.cpp, with the prototypes in Rdraws.h. Even with all the `#includes` and `externs`, I'm getting a "symbol not found" compiler error at the first function call in main().

Here's what I have:

```
// Rdraws.cpp
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
#include <cmath>

#include "Rdraws.h"
#include "rng.h"

extern RNG rgen // this is the PRNG used in the simulation; global scope

void rmultinom( double p_trans[], int numTrials, int numTrans, int numEachTrans[] )
{ // function 1 def 
}

void rmultinom( const double p_trans[], const int numTrials, int numTrans, int numEachTrans[]) 
{ // function 2 def
}

int rbinom( int nTrials, double pLeaving )
{ // function 3 def
}

// Rdraws.h

#ifndef RDRAWS
#define RDRAWS

void rmultinom( double[], int, int, int[] );
void rmultinom( const double[], const int, int, int[] );
int rbinom( int, double );

#endif

// main.cpp
...
#include "Rdraws.h"
...

extern void rmultinom(double p_trans[], int numTrials, int numTrans, int numEachTrans[]);
extern void rmultinom(const double p_trans[], const int numTrials, int numTrans, int numEachTrans[]);
extern int rbinom( int n, double p );

RNG rgen; // global PRNG object created for simulation

int main() { ... }
```

I'm pretty new to programming. If there's a dramatically smarter way to do this, I'd love to know.

---

**Update**

I'm a moron and didn't realize I still hadn't included Rdraws.cpp in my compiler. As a poster noted, I also forgot a semicolon.

*I would still appreciate suggestions if the method outlined here could be improved upon.*

Comment: Meh. For someone “pretty new to programming” this looks quite good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which compiler are you using? You need to first compile all of the source files into object files and then link all of the object files together.

Example:

```
g++ -c -Wall -O2 main.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -O2 Rdraws.cpp
```

And then to get the executable...

```
g++ -s main.o Rdraws.o
```

Comment: Holy... I'm sorry, I wasn't including Rdraws.cpp in the compile. <very embarrassed> Now dealing with a "Rdraws.cpp error: expected initializer before 'void'."

Comment: @Sarah: That will be the missing semicolon after `extern RNG rgen`

Comment: @Sarah:  That's because you left out a semicolon in the line just before the first `void`.  Since it's a variable declaration, the compiler was looking for an initializer or semicolon.

Comment: @David and @e.James. Thank you. I'm going for more coffee before I continue programming today.

Comment: @Brian. I am using g++. I am currently typing g++ main.cpp rng.cpp [... *.cpp] -o stuff.out and then running ./stuff.out. Should I not do this?

Comment: @Sarah:  I've never understood why compilers don't recognize low caffeine errors.  It might be difficult, but think of the problems it would solve!

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

- <s>I don't see the variable `rgen`
  defined anywhere. Its been declared
  in the `Rdraws.cpp` but the
  definition is missing.</s>
- To use the global variable and
  functions you need to separately
  compile(just compile no linking)
  `main.cpp` and `Rdraws.cpp` into
  `main.o` and `Rdraws.o` and then link
  them to get the final executable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Brian R. Bondy has your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638911/c-trouble-declaring-and-recognizing-global-functions/2638937#2638937). I would just like to point out that you do not need those `extern` function declarations in your main.cpp. The declarations are already made in the Rdraws.h header file, which you include.